# Filter python dictionary with filter() to list of dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary consists of string or dictionaries

```
parameters = {
"date": {'date':"2015-12-13"},
"name": "Nick",
"product": "BT Adapter",
"transaction-id": ""
}
```

And i need to get list like `['2015-12-13', 'BT Adapter', 'Nick']`.

If it has no dictionaries in it, `print filter(lambda x: x if len(x) > 0 and type(x) is not dict else None, parameters.values())` works perfectly, but with dictionary in it i tried to extract it's value with

```
print filter(lambda x: x if len(x) > 0 and type(x) is not dict else map(lambda y: x[y], x.keys()), parameters.values())
```

and i get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'`. 
How all values can be extracted?

Comment: `len(x) > 0` is `False` for an empty string, so the `else` part is executed and `str` has no method `keys`.

Comment: As an aside, it's more idiomatic to use `not isinstance(x, dict)` rather than `type(x) is not dict`.  The meaning is slightly different, but it's think closer to what you want.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provided the output that you'd like to obtain given that dictionary as input... it's not clear at all how you want to handle dictionary values or empty strings... BTW: `map(lambda y: x[y], x.keys())` is basically just `x.values()`

Comment: @Bakuriu it returns `[{'date': '2015-12-13'}, 'BT Adapter', 'Nick']`, but i need value of `'date'` to be included in list as string instead of raw dictionary.

Comment: ... you can that output simply by: `filter(None, parameters.values())`. where the `None` is equivalent to `lambda x: x`.

Comment: @Bakuriu still `[{'date': '2015-12-13'}, '', 'BT Adapter', 'Nick']` or `[{'date': '2015-12-13'}, 'BT Adapter', 'Nick']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def magic(params):
    dicts = [params]
    values = []

    while len(dicts):
        d = dicts.pop()

        for value in d.values():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                dicts.append(value)
            elif isinstance(value, basestring) and len(value) > 0:
                values.append(value)

    return values


def main():
    parameters = {
        "date": {'date': "2015-12-13"},
        "name": "Nick",
        "product": "BT Adapter",
        "transaction-id": ""
    }

    print(magic(parameters))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

You are misusing the `filter` function. The argument to `filter` is a *predicate*, which is a function that returns a true/false value and filter returns the elements *from the second argument* for which that function returns true.

For example:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: 5, [1,2,3,4,5])))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Since `bool(5) == True` filter returns all the elements.

Since you pass as second argument the value `parameters.values()` there is no way to obtain your expected result by just passing a predicate to filter.

What you want to do is something like:

```
from itertools import chain

def listify(value):
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        return value.values()
    elif value:
        return [value]
    return ()

print(list(chain.from_iterable(map(listify, parameters.values()))))
```

So first you convert the values into sequences, and then you concatenate them using `chain.from_iterable`.

The empty values are removed by `listify` since it returns an empty sequence in that case. Sample run:

```
In [2]: parameters = {
   ...: "date": {'date':"2015-12-13"},
   ...: "name": "Nick",
   ...: "product": "BT Adapter",
   ...: "transaction-id": ""
   ...: }

In [3]: print(list(chain.from_iterable(map(listify, parameters.values()))))
['2015-12-13', 'Nick', 'BT Adapter']
```

Also: it doesn't make sense to write a complex lambda function with nested conditionals, so just use a `def` and write it properly. `lambda`s are fine only if they are extremely short.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are trying to do a `map` operation with your `filter`, showing a bit of a misunderstanding. The function in a filter essentially must return `True` or `False` to determine whether to keep a certain value in the second argument, so it does not make sense to filter in this way:

```
filter(lambda x: x if len(x) > 0 and type(x) is not dict else None, parameters.values())
```

Better:

```
filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0 and type(x) is not dict, parameters.values())
# better idiom
filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0 and not isinstance(x, dict), parameters.values())
```

This is especially true for your next attempt, which attempts to `map` *inside* a filter function. It's better to think of this as a two-step process:

1. Remove empty strings/lists (anything where `lex(x) < 1`)
2. Get values of dictionaries

Let's try this instead, if you need to use `filter`. I'm using Python3, which means that I have to do a lot of ugly `list` casting:

```
list(map(lambda x: list(x.values()) if isinstance(x, dict) else x, filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, parameters.values())))
```

This produces:

```
[['2015-12-13'], 'BT Adapter', 'Nick']
```

This is not pythonic at all: `filter` and `map` are much more at home in list comprehensions like the following:

```
[list(v.values()) if isinstance(v, dict) else v for v in parameters.values() if len(v) > 0]
```

Let me know if you also need to flatten the list after getting the dictionary values.

Answer (score 0):

It is failing for the last attribute "transaction-id" because its length is 0.

This would work for you:

```
print filter(lambda x: x if len(x) >= 0 and type(x) is not dict else map(lambda y: x[y], x.keys()), parameters.values())
```